# Windows 10 Taskbar Date Not Showing on Monday

Tags: windows-10

I've just installed a fresh Windows 10 Pro and use custom format for taskbar date.

`Short date: ddd, dd MMM`

This is the first time I use this format.

It works fine for Tuesday-Sunday, but on Monday it is simply a blank line.

[image: not showing date]
[image: works as expected on another day]

It appears the bug only occurs when using `ddd` with `MMM`, but `MMMM` works fine.
It works fine with format `ddd, dd yyyy` and `ddd, dd MMMM`

Any idea about this bug? Is there a way to solve this?

EDIT: Tried every other month, and it works just fine. Only May that has a problem with Monday.

EDIT: Here is my Windows information

| Info | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Edition | Windows 10 Pro |
| Version | 21H1 |
| OS build | 19043.1706 |
| Experience | Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4170.0 |

Comment: Can you proide the exact build you are using?

Comment: @Ramhound Windows 10 Pro, version 21H1, OS Build 19043.1706, Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4170.0

Comment: Definitely seems like you found a bug.  To report it, goto **Feedback Hub**; (Optionally) Sign-in with your Microsoft Live account; click **Report a problem**; fill-in the details (be as specific as possible); press **Next** (etc.); choose a category (eg, Settings / Date and Time Settings); attach screenshots; agree to send diagnostics data to Microsoft; then press **Submit**.

Comment: In the meantime (as a potential short-term work-around), see if making text size bigger/smaller; change the size of apps and text (scaling); turn system icons on or off; use small or large taskbar icons; or any other taskbar setting makes any difference.